# Use Dimensions in custom style

Tags: android, android-styles

In Android I've got the following:

**dimens.xml**

```xml
<dimen name="buttonMarginRL">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="buttonMarginTB">5dp</dimen>
```

**style.xml**

```xml
<style name="my_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>

    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/buttonMarginRL</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/buttonMarginRL</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/buttonMarginTB</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/buttonMarginTB</item>
</style>
```

And I'm adding it to a button view:

**someFragment.xml**

```xml
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/my_button" />
```

But the margins do not get applied. When putting *10dp* and *5dp* directly into the my_button style it works as expected. Is it possible within Android to use values specified in dimens.xml to be used in custom styles or may the dimens-values only be applied to view's directly?

Comment: Are dimen items between <resources> tag?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late for an answer but it is for people that are searching this kind of an error. There is a false reference to the parent. Just change the following line from styles.xml

```
<style name="my_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
```

to

```
<style name="my_button">
```

In addition, you can add all the common properties of my_button to its reference in styles and then add the following line to the **Theme's style**. By doing that, you can skip the reference **android:buttonStyle** in the activity's xml.

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/my_button</item>
```